# RecyclerView con rayas blancas

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, recyclerview

Tengo un RecyclerView que se le ponen rayitas blancas en los bordes y no entiendo el por qué salen.

Lo defino asi:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/digimonFields"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```

Y hago que el adapter lo pinte así en la aplicación:

```
binding.digimonFields.apply {
                adapter = FieldAdapter(digimon.fields)
                layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL, false)
                addItemDecoration(DividerItemDecoration(context,DividerItemDecoration.HORIZONTAL))
            }
```

Pero al final el resultado que obtengo es este, donde yo nunca dirijo el estilo a que haya una línea blanca en la separación. ¿Hay alguna manera de quitarla? Gracias de antemano.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para solucionar esto, puedes definir a tu `DividerItemDecoration` un color negro mediante `.setDrawable()`:

```
binding.digimonFields.apply {
                adapter = FieldAdapter(digimon.fields)
                layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL, false)
                //addItemDecoration(DividerItemDecoration(context,DividerItemDecoration.HORIZONTAL))
                val itemDecoration = DividerItemDecoration(context,DividerItemDecoration.HORIZONTAL)
                //Define color negro.
                itemDecoration.setDrawable(ColorDrawable(android.R.color.black))
                addItemDecoration(itemDecoration)         
            }
```

Comment: Gracias! La verdad es que lo quería sin color, simplemente que no se dibujara ningún borde, así que con ColorDrawable vacío me valió. Gracias!